# Squashing pushed commits into one commit

Tags: git

I'm currently trying to squash two pushed commits into one single commit. After searching around on, I've found that commits can effectively be squashed by resetting three commits ago. I did this, but attempting to commit the changes again results in a message stating that I'm committing to a detatched head.

What do I do from here?

Comment: If it was pushed to central repo, don't do that!

Answer (score 3):

It's generally a very bad idea to rewrite commits that have been shared with others, but if you're aware of the pitfalls and are OK with the consequences, then...

1. `git rebase -i <sha_of_commit_older_than_the_oldest_you_want_to_squash>`
2. if necessary, reorder the lines in the interactive rebase recipe to put all of the commits you want to squash together next to each other
3. of the commits you want to squash together, mark the second and later commits with `squash`
4. save, exit, and wait for rebase to finish
5. `git push -f`
6. get ready to defend yourself against a mob with pitchforks and torches

Comment: The last one made my day! :)

Comment: Im not sure if this is explained but this only can squash commits that are parent/child not commits that are far apart.

Comment: @SaulOrtega:  You can actually squash commits that are far apart—you just need to reorder the lines in the interactive rebase recipe to suit your needs.

Comment: @RichardHansen Yes, I failed to explain what I mean, I meant you have to put the commits you want to squash together like you explained, because the first time I did it, I thought that I just had to write squash next to all the commits that I wanted to squash into a single one, and I think this is a common mistake.

Comment: @SaulOrtega: Good point.  I updated my answer to mention reordering the lines.