# Is it possible to squash two pushed commits from the same branch into a single commit with git?

Tags: git

I want to make 2 commits into one commit so if later in the future I have to revert that commit I don't have to remember what were the two commits I have to revert and also because those two commits are referring to the same change it would be a good idea to squash them into one.

So, I've read some ideas on how to do it like this one:

[Squashing pushed commits into one commit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17100738/squashing-pushed-commits-into-one-commit)
but the problem is that with this approach I can only squash the commits that are close by each other. So I was wondering if there's a better way to approach this.

Comment: You can reorder commits in an interactive rebase as well. Just move them next to eachother and change the status of the one on the bottom to "s" and it will be squashed into the one above it.

Comment: Not withstanding what I said in an answer, if the commits are already pushed then editing the history will potentially cause issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `rebase` command to move the two commits so that they are next to each other, and then squash them together. `rebase -i` is useful for this, because you can select the commits that you want to move around in a text editor.